# SUM Function in VBA - sum of different columns in one row

Tags: excel, vba

Can I use the SUM function to sum two or more columns in the same row?

```
Example:  
Column  : A B C D E  
Total   : 1 2 3 4 5
TotColAC: 4 6 (TotColBD)
```

Is it possible to use the SUM function or is there another way?

Thank you!

Comment: @@user2063626, do you know how to do it in vba?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using VBA. It will add cells from A1 to E1. You can modify as per your requirement.

```
Sub Add()
    Dim totalAtoE As Double
    totalAtoC = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:E1"))
End Sub
```

only A1 and C1

```
Sub AddAandC()
    Dim totalAandC As Double
    totalAandC = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1"), Range("C1"))
End Sub
```

as per your comment

```
Sub Add()

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Integer, totalAtoC As Double, FinalSum As Double
lastRow = Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    totalAtoC = totalAtoC + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A" & i & ":C" & i))
Next
FinalSum = totalAtoC

End Sub
```

Comment: How do I get the sum of two columns that are separated by a column? Let say I want the sum of column A and column C without adding column B. Is it possible?

Comment: @yes      totalAandC = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1"), Range("C1"))

Comment: I would like to use the lastRow variable into the range, how can I embed the variable in? let say the lastRow is 651 and I would like to put the add the sum of column A and column B in row 650 and put the result in row 651 but hard coding the number 561 into the range or declare lastRow = 651

Comment: Range("A" & lastRow).Value

Comment: @Jeannette Liu if you are happy with the solution please vote